# How to fix this "You have ad crawler errors, which can result in lost revenue" google adsense on Blogger

Tags: blogger, google-ads-api, adsense

The Affected url was [www.exporakey.com.ng/p/.html?m=1](http://www.exporakey.com.ng/p/.html?m=1)

[The screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2yS6.png)

Comment: Did you set up Google Search Console for your website?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse..

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your Google Search Console account.
2. Find the 'Removals' on the left-hand menu.
3. 'New Request' and then choose the 'Clear Cached URL' tab.
4. **Copy and paste the URL** you have the problem with.
5. Choose 'This URL only'.
6. Click 'Next', complete the process, and wait for a week.

This should work but if not, let me know so let's see if the cause is something else.

Comment: Done successfully, waiting for them to implement! Thankz